# Remove List from List partial match Python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to remove a list from a list if it has a partial match

List 1

```
[['Person1', 'www.google.co.uk', '1'], ['Person2', 'www.amazon.co.uk', '2'],['Person3', 'www.google.co.uk', '2']]
```

List 2

```
[['Person1', 'www.google.co.uk', '1'], ['Person2', 'www.amazon.co.uk', '2'],['Person1', 'www.google.co.uk', '2']]
```

Desired Output:

```
['Person2', 'www.amazon.co.uk', '2']
```

At the moment I have the following code with will remove it as long as it is a full match:

```
[i for i in List1 if i in List2]
```

but as the number can vary i want to be a able to match on the first two entries so it will not matter what number is in the last column

Comment: Why isn't `['Person1', 'www.google.co.uk', '1']` in the result?

Comment: How are you defining partial match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
l1 = [['Person1', 'www.google.co.uk', '1'], ['Person2', 'www.amazon.co.uk', '2'],['Person3', 'www.google.co.uk', '2']]

l2 = [['Person1', 'www.google.co.uk', '2'], ['Person2', 'www.amazon.co.uk', '2'],['Person1', 'www.google.co.uk', '2']]

print ([ x for x in l1 if x[0:2] in [ l[0:2] for l in l2 ] ])
```

Output:

```
[['Person1', 'www.google.co.uk', '1'], ['Person2', 'www.amazon.co.uk', '2']]
```

Here you check for each sublist in `l1` if values at index 0 and 1 are found in `[ l[0:2] for l in l2 ]`. The later is the same than `l2` at the notable exception that it contains only two index by sublist instead of more. So you can use `in`.